# Strange BLE connection state

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sometimes, the onConnectionStateChange() callback is called with status 22.
It is said to be a "Bond" error.

But what could be the cause behind it?
And how to avoid it?

Comment: I'm also facing exactly the same issue, device disconnection with status 22
Did you find any root cause from app level? @Phantomaxx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235163

Answer (score 3):

22 just means "connection terminated by local host" (defined by the Bluetooth specification). Some examples why the host terminates:

1. You call disconnect().
2. The GATT timer times out, which happens if the remote device doesn't respond to a request in 30 seconds.
3. The SMP timer times out, which happens if the pairing process doesn't make any progress in 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
However, I still don't see the reason why that happens. I clearly did not call disconnect() at that time and I did not run a pairing process.  
The only thing that may seem coherent with your second point is that, indeed, that happened after approximately 30 seconds from when I called connectGatt.  
I should add that, this happened when I turned off and on my device after I wrote a script to the RN4020 (This is the BLE chip I have on my device)

Comment: You could use the HCI log (snoop log) on Android or use an air sniffer to see which packet that stalls the transmission.

Comment: I think I better figured out when that happens.  
Sometimes, after connection and when discoverServices is requested, the onServicesDiscovered callback is not called, somehow the bluetooth gatt is stalled, and it ends by issuing a disconnection in onConnectionStateChanged.
If we could tell why the services discovery stalls, this issue could be solved

Comment: That's why you should check the hci log ;)

Comment: I will
Thanks Emil :)

Comment: The "Controller Error Codes" section of the core bluetooth specification has all these enumerated and extensively described: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/